# about the using of template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the operator for matrix multiplication.

But I receive the error message:

```
<source>:29:16: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('matrix<3, 3>' (aka 'array<array<int, 3>, 3>') and 'matrix<3, 2>' (aka 'array<array<int, 2>, 3>'))
    auto c = a * b;
             ~ ^ ~
<source>:12:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long' vs 'int')
auto operator* (const matrix<row, shared>& a, const matrix<shared, column>& b) -> matrix<row, column> {
     ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:29:16: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('matrix<3, 3>' (aka 'array<array<int, 3>, 3>') and 'matrix<3, 2>' (aka 'array<array<int, 2>, 3>'))
    auto c = a * b;
             ~ ^ ~
<source>:12:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long' vs 'int')
auto operator* (const matrix<row, shared>& a, const matrix<shared, column>& b) -> matrix<row, column> {
     ^
```

I'm wondering what is wrong in my code, or do I misunderstand how to use templates.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using std::array;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<int row, int column>
using matrix = array<array<int, column>, row>;

template<int row, int shared, int column>
auto operator* (const matrix<row, shared>& a, const matrix<shared, column>& b) -> matrix<row, column> {
    int row_index, column_index, index;
    matrix<row, column> c;
    
    for(row_index = 0; row_index < row; ++row_index) {
        for(column_index = 0; column_index < column; ++column_index) {
            for(index = 0; index < shared; ++index) {
                c[row_index][column_index] += a[row_index][index] * b[index][column_index];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(void) {
    matrix<3, 3> a = {{{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 7}, {2, 4, 6}}};
    matrix<3, 2> b = {{{2,3}, {3,4}, {6,2}}};
    auto c = a * b;
    for(auto line : c) {
        for(auto num : line) {
            cout << num << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I change `int` to `unsigned long` then it works.

```
template<unsigned long row, unsigned long shared, unsigned long column>
auto operator* (const matrix<row, shared>& a, const matrix<shared, column>& b) -> matrix<row, column> {
    int row_index, column_index, index;
    matrix<row, column> c;
    
    for(auto& line : c) {
        for(auto& num : line) {
            num = 0;
        }
    }
    
    for(row_index = 0; row_index < row; ++row_index) {
        for(column_index = 0; column_index < column; ++column_index) {
            for(index = 0; index < shared; ++index) {
                c[row_index][column_index] += a[row_index][index] * b[index][column_index];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: You can't multiply whole arrays. Do you want to multiply a specific element of each matrix?

Comment: Please post a [mre] and the full error output from the compiler as text not an image

Comment: The code in the image is not posted as code. Don't do that. Also understand that C++ doesn't automatically know how to add your custom types

Comment: sorry about that, it's my first time using stack overflow, I'm already add the whole code for now, is that appropriate now?

Comment: while I'm very shocked to find out the fact that you can edit other people's questions in stack overflow, I think I do know more about how to ask questions here. Thanks, Alen!!

Comment: Only experienced users have the privileges to do so and they can be revoked if abused, you can also revert other peoples edits if you don't like them (but please don't do that when people are trying to improve your question)

Comment: Defining operator without your own class (and alias is not a new type) involved is risky (3rd part might add operators in future conflicting with yours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimensions of `std::array` are specified to be of type `size_t`. Even though you have defined your `matrix` alias with `int` template arguments you still end up with a `std::array` with `size_t` dimensions. The compiler is unable to automatically deduce your template argument as their types don't match, if you look at the full error message it even tells you this as a hint:

```
candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long' vs 'int')
```

You can also remove deduction from the equation to show that your function is at least callable:

```
auto c = operator*<3,3,2>(a, b);
```

This does compile but is presumably not how you want to use it.

`unsigned long` is probably the same type as `size_t` on your platform which is why changing your type to `unsigned int` fixes the problem.

Fully working cross platform code would be:

```
template<size_t row, size_t column>
using matrix = array<array<int, column>, row>;

template<size_t row, size_t shared, size_t column>
auto operator* (const matrix<row, shared>& a, const matrix<shared, column>& b) -> matrix<row, column> {
    size_t row_index, column_index, index;
    matrix<row, column> c;
    
    for(row_index = 0; row_index < row; ++row_index) {
        for(column_index = 0; column_index < column; ++column_index) {
            for(index = 0; index < shared; ++index) {
                c[row_index][column_index] += a[row_index][index] * b[index][column_index];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I understand now